# Controlar teclas pulsadas en C

Tags: c

Estoy haciendo un proyecto el cual me pide que haga determinadas acciones cuando se pulse la combinación de teclas Ctrl+D y la flecha hacia arriba. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo? ¿Ctrl+D está representada por alguna señal de interrupción que se podría manejar?
Gracias.

Comment: Nos ayudarás a responder si especificas en qué sistema operativo piensas trabajar.

Comment: El proyecto lo estoy desarrollando en WSL corriendo ubuntu, aunque el sistema operativo objetivo es MacOS. Gracias.

Comment: ¿Estás desarrollando en Windows Subsystem for Linux? Eso no es de MacOS. Por cierto, qué intentaste?

Comment: Sé que no es MacOS pero es lo más "similar" que puedo instalar en un ordenador Windows. Por ahora lo que he probado es a utilizar la función signal para hacer un manejador para una interrupción, pero no he encontrado ninguna equivalencia entre una interrupción y la combinación de teclas Ctrl+D. Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

La solución varía según los sistemas operativos. En Linux, se puede resolver programando puramente en C; sin embargo, para el sistema Windows, depende de la API interna que tiene un comportamiento más restrictivo al programar directamente para el sistema.

La biblioteca [*conio.h*](https://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate4/EN/html/devwin32/coniohpart_xml.html) es bien conocida y documentada por la comunidad de desarrolladores, al igual que la biblioteca [windows.h](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/win32/learnwin32/your-first-windows-program) , que es más simple que conio.h. Estas bibliotecas proporcionan funciones que se pueden utilizar para capturar las teclas.

utilizando windows.h:

```
#include <windows.h>

int  CtrlActivar(){
    return (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CONTROL) & 0x8000) != 0;
}

int  FlechaHaciaArriba(){
    return (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP) & 0x8000) != 0;
}

int main(){
    while (1) {
        if ( CtrlActivar() &&  FlechaHaciaArriba()) {
            
            printf("Hello");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

La biblioteca `conio.h` encontrará una gran variedad desarrollada por terceros tanto para **Linux** como para **Windows**, fácilmente disponible en [GitHub](https://github.com/search?q=conio.h&type=repositories).

Comment: Es importante señalar que `windows.h` no te dará los eventos de teclado: tan sólo te informará del estado actual de las teclas (pulsado o no pulsado).

Answer (score 1):

Existen varias funciones, para leer una entrada por teclado.

Un primer tipo, general, de función, detiene la ejecución del programa, y espera a que se pulse una tecla.

Un segundo tipo de función, para esto, tomará en el momento, el código asociado a la tecla, y lo devuelve como resultado; Pero a diferencia del primer tipo, si no se esta pulsando ninguna tecla, devolvera 0, y continuará con el flujo de ejecución del programa.

Yo lo que haría para esto, es ..

- Crearme un programa al efecto (como el que comparto por aquí, o similar) que registre en bucle, todas las teclas o combinaciones de teclas, que pulse.
- Utilizando el segundo tipo de función, que fluye, y evitando la salida de los caracteres por pantalla, para lo que nos va a servir por ejemplo, la.función `getch()`.
- Y haria que me imprima los valores, los codigos asociados a las combinaciones de teclas que quiero averiguar, para anotar las secuencias de codigos que generen que necesite controlar.

Este código, escribira por pantalla, las secuencias de codigos de combinaciones de teclas, separados por un retorno de carro, a la linea.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
        
        
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {   
    int key=0;
    bool writed=false;
    printf("Pulse enter para terminar\n\n");
    
    do
      { 
      key=getch();
              
      if (writed&&key==0)
         {
         printf("\n\n");
         writed=false;
         }
                  
         printf("%i ",key);  
             
         if (key!=0)
           writed=true;
               
       }while (key!=10);

    return 0;
    }
```

- Finalmente programaría con las funciones que necesite, el reconocimiento de esas secuencias de codigos, para ejecutar condicionalmente (con una serie de if() ) lo que corresponda.